# VB.Net: Subtracting time values possible? ((6:00 AM - 8 hours) = 10:00 PM)

Tags: vb.net

Another newbie question here.
As stated in the question, I need to be able to compute for the time elapsed by getting the difference between two times.

**PROBLEM:** *Employee can only login EVERY 8 HOURS.*

**GOAL:** If difference is > 8 hours, employee can login again.

How can I code this? Or is there another way around the scenario?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to answer this yourself? Did you try to write some code? Did you ... try anything?

Comment: I'm asking if this is possible firsthand.

Comment: If it is possible to subtract times? Yes it is possible, I bet you could implement it yourself if you just know basic arithmetic.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. See `TimeSpan.Subtract` in the documentation. Also, questions that ask "Is it possible?" are highly frowned upon here, because there are only three answers to that question: "Yes, it is", "No, it isn't", and "Probably. Can you be more specific about what you're asking?". If the first two are not helpful to you, the third applies and you should restate your question more specifically (including what you've written in the title).

Comment: "I'm asking if this is possible firsthand". Well, actually, no, you're not.  You asked how to code it, not whether it could be done.  All you had to do was type *vb.net subtract time* into a search engine and you would have found that it was possible and quite possibly how to do it too.  You obviously made no effort at all if you didn't even Google it.  There are plenty of people here who want to help but we're not here to be taken advantage of.  We aren't here to do your work and even your thinking for you so that you don't have to.

Comment: I don't even know there's such code as vb.net subtract time. Now I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have hardcoded the date-times, but in actual code you would use e.g. `LoginDateTime = Now` to remember the date-time that the user logged in.

The code below compares the current date-time with the login date-time and if they are greater than eight hours apart, it asks the user to "login again", otherwise it says "login okay".

```
Dim LoginDateTime As Date = New Date(2014, 6, 4, 22, 0, 0)
Dim CurrentDateTime As Date = New Date(2014, 6, 5, 7, 0, 0)

If CurrentDateTime - LoginDateTime > New TimeSpan(8, 0, 0) Then
  MsgBox("Login again")
Else
  MsgBox("Login okay")
End If
```

Comment: I thought it was pretty self-explanatory, but I have added some explanation.

Comment: The TimeSpan object is not really needed.  You could just do `If (CurrentDateTime - LoginDateTime).TotalHours > 8`